# mysql group by and sum results from 2 fields from two tables

Tags: mysql

I have `bills`,`bill_details`,`customers` and `suppliers` tables
I need to make a query to return the total sales and total returns from `area` filed in `customers` and `suppliers` table

I need the sum of the same areas of all customers and suppliers

```
select c.area,s.area,
        sum( IF(b.bill_type = 'sales', bd.quantity*(bd.price-bd.discount), 0) ) as totalSales,
        sum( IF(b.bill_type = 'salesReturns', bd.quantity*(bd.price-bd.discount), 0) ) as totalReturns,
        sum( IF(b.bill_type = 'sales', bd.quantity, 0) ) as sales,
        sum( IF(b.bill_type = 'salesReturns', bd.quantity, 0) ) as returns
    from adsl_bill b
    left join bill_details bd on bd.bill_num = b.bill_num && bd.bill_type = b.bill_type
    left join customers c on b.customer  = c.id && b.customer_type = 1
    left join suppliers s on b.customer  = s.id && b.customer_type = 2

group by area
```

I know `group by area` is wrong statement but I just need to group and sum with both s.area and c.area

Comment: You can `GROUP BY c.area, s.area`

Comment: yes but this will return  separated values from each table, I need it to be only one value of the same area

Comment: Then you'll probably want to join the tables on the area too, otherwise it doesn't really make sense..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
select ifnull(c.area, s.area) as area,
        sum( IF(b.bill_type = 'sales', bd.quantity*(bd.price-bd.discount), 0) ) as totalSales,
        sum( IF(b.bill_type = 'salesReturns', bd.quantity*(bd.price-bd.discount), 0) ) as totalReturns,
        sum( IF(b.bill_type = 'sales', bd.quantity, 0) ) as sales,
        sum( IF(b.bill_type = 'salesReturns', bd.quantity, 0) ) as returns
    from adsl_bill b
    left join bill_details bd on bd.bill_num = b.bill_num && bd.bill_type = b.bill_type
    left join customers c on b.customer  = c.id && b.customer_type = 1
    left join suppliers s on b.customer  = s.id && b.customer_type = 2
group by area
```